# Prospective Search Location-Based Searches

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The [search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) supports location-based searches with the [Geopoint class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/geopointclass), which enables [searching with a distance constraint, and other goodies](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Performing_Location-Based_Searches).

I have also noticed that the Search and Prospective Search APIs share a common query syntax, and a common feel. So I wouldn't be surprised if these geosearching features appeared for prospective search

So my question is: Is there is someway to have similar geosearching capabilities in prospective search either through an appengine API or any other library?

Cheers!